# Контроллер для интерфейса в java?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Хорошая ли идея для контроллера создавать интерфейс?

Если да, то как лучше сделать аннотацию `@RequestMapping()`?

Прописать ее в интерфейсе, или в контроллере, либо и там и там?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создание интерфейса ради интерфейса вряд ли хорошая идея.
А вот если вам это реально нужно, например для AOP, то это разумное решение.
В таком случае аннотацию необходимо размещать на методы интерфейса ([RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)):

> **NOTE:** When using controller interfaces (e.g. for AOP proxying), make sure to consistently put all your mapping annotations - such as @RequestMapping and @SessionAttributes - on the controller interface rather than on the implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна реализация конкретного интерфейса в нескольких классах, можешь создать, например какой нибудь AbstractController. А аннотировать надо в классах которые реализуют какой то интерфейс. В обоих местах точно не надо)